# Facebook-Ios get the number of users i have just tagged in a post, some questions

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanna get the number of users i have just tagged in a post (in my profile) by Facebook sdk. I have read about:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent
FBSDKSharePhoto
```

But seems that theri delegation doesn't return anything about the number of friends tagged, so i can't use it.
Maybe an alternative is a custom friends picker and a share action with Graph api, something like:

Login with fb -> UiTableview with content filled with graph endpoint "taggable_friends" -> launch the share action -> Return the number of tagged friends

My question are:

- There is a way with graph api to know how many friends are tagged in a post (i have to post in my own profile)?
- If the endpoint "taggable_friends" is deprecated (i can't find in Graph explorer), what is the actual alternative ?
- "taggable_friends" returns only friends how have already my fb app installed or all my friends?

Comment: First of all, what do you need this information for? (Please be aware that you are not allowed to “reward” users in any way for posting or tagging people, or to require them to tag a certain number of people or something like that. If you haven’t done so already, you should go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).) // `taggable_friends` is not deprecated, and it returns all friends, not just app users.

Comment: thank you, i'll mark as a correct answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what do you need this information for?

Please be aware that you are not allowed to “reward” users in any way for posting or tagging people, or to require them to tag a certain number of people or something like that. If you haven’t done so already, you should go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

`taggable_friends` is not deprecated, and it returns all friends, not just app users.

---

If you have a legitimate use case for finding out how many people where tagged, you could read the post details back from the API, after the post is made. The `message_tags` field contains info about the tags, so you could simply check how many elements this field contains. (I don’t know though how tag review affects this, if people have their FB settings so that they need to confirm being tagged first.)